# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in <filename> on line <ifconditioin statement>

Tags: php, class, fatal-error

I get the error for the following code

```
     class Myclass {
              //...variables

              public function getName() {
                       return $this->strName;
              }

              public function checkDup() {
                      if(empty($this->getName())) {  //HERE IS THE ERROR
                        $strMessage = 'Please Enter First Name';
                        return $strMessage;
                      }
              }
     }

     $a = new Myclass (); //assume constructor is present and variables are set in class
     $a->checkDup();
```

What could be the solution? 
My getName() function returns the name of the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong here.

I should be referring to the class member variable using $this and not call the getName() function again inside the class. This changes the function to :

```
          public function checkDup() {
                  if(empty($this->strName)) {  //HERE IS THE SOLUTION
                    $strMessage = 'Please Enter First Name';
                    return $strMessage;
                  }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
if(empty($this->getName())) {
```

to

```
$name = $this->getName();
if( empty($name) ) {
...
```

**empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error**

Answer (score 0):

the `empty` construct is a bit silly that way.  see [the manual](https://www.php.net/empty):

> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
> result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
> empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I am aware of what you've mentioned. But here, I am just returning the value of the class variable.

"Instead, use trim($name) == false."
Beware, when using this context. This cannot be used if the value in $name is numeric 0. Which could be the requirement. Instead we could do this:-

$name = trim($name); if(empty($name)) { //yourcode }

Comment: yes, you are *returning* something.  and you *cannot* do that.  `empty($this->foo)` works, `empty($this->getFoo())` does not, `$foo = $this->getFoo(); empty($foo);` does again.  the manual is pretty clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like any of the answers here. Yes you can reference `$this->strName` directly. But what if you can't? What if `getName()` has some important functionality?

Then the only option is to create another variable? `$var = $this->getName();`.
That also sucks.

Generically whenever I access a class property or function dynamically I enclose it in braces `{}` so:

1. I'll know it's dynamic.
2. I'll get meaningful errors if there are any.

Examples:

```
$this->{$variable};
$this->{$class->property};
$this->{$class->method()};
$this->{function()};
$this->{$array['index']};
```